# Creating a Composite Variable

Tags: statistics

I'm seeking creative inputs for the following challenge: I have two variables at the county level—one indicating the percentage of households without vehicles and another representing the percentage of people using public transport for their daily commute. For instance, in County X, 3% of households lack vehicles, and 2% of people use public transport for commuting. In County Y, these figures are 40% and 55%, respectively, etc (....). My focus is on understanding access to abortion providers. The overarching concept is that counties with a high percentage of households lacking cars but a low percentage of people using public transport face greater challenges in accessing abortion providers compared to counties with a high percentage of car-less households and a substantial portion of people using public transport. I operate under the assumption that counties with a significant number of people utilizing public transport have a well-established public transportation system.

I'm uncertain about the methodology for computing this variable, and I welcome any guidance and ideas. Many thanks!